# Pywintypes error when running an adodbapi package python query

Tags: python, adodb, pywin32, adodbapi

I am having difficulty installing adodbapi and running a script which uses SQL to connect and run a DAX query using adodbapi. I have run into this error on multiple machines.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to an MSOLAP update. I have copied an old MSOLAP.dll file (version 15) and overwritten the newer one (version 16).

https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1820